# Special characters like ä, ö, ü

Tags: google-app-engine, utf-8, special-characters

I’m trying to get special characters like the German Umlaut (ä, ö, ü) working with the `Google App Engine`, but sadly it dosen't work. The Eclipse text file encoding is set to `UTF-8`, I use `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` in my `index.html` and the `web.xml` is also using `encoding="utf-8"`.

If I compile my project locally, the characters are shown correctly. If I deploy it to the google appspot the characters are shown like this: `��`. I checked also the Browser encoding, this is set to `UTF-8`, what did I miss?

**Edit**
Here is a example which works locally but not online:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>ä ö ü</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="profile" action="">
        <select name="p" size="1">
            <option value="1">ä</option>
            <option value="2">ö</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Edit2**
I could isolate the problem. At the start I use the google channel api to communicate with the clients. Here I write the token to the users. This is the problem. Here is the code:

I guess I have to convert to UTF-8, but where?

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("index.html");
CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.allocate(16384);
reader.read(buffer);
reader.close();

String index = new String(buffer.array());
index = index.replaceAll("\\{\\{ token \\}\\}", token);
index = index.replaceAll("\\{\\{ user \\}\\}", account);

resp.getWriter().write(index);
```

Why the characters are not shown correctly online?

Comment: You're probably not handling unicode correctly in your app - but since you haven't shown us any code, we can't really help. You also haven't specified if this is static data, or something you're rendering dynamically.

Comment: Ye, I’m sorry. The issues occur by static data, for example in the index html. Please see my **Edit**. Thanks

Comment: Is the document actually encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: Yes it is UTF-8 without BOM. Locally everything works.

Comment: If the browser is interpreting the document as UTF-8 and is misinterpreting some characters, that points towards the document not actually being UTF-8 encoded. At least on the server. Try selecting a different encoding in the browser and see if the characters are correctly interpreted then (likely Windows Latin 1).

Comment: I found the reason for the problem, see my second edit. If i uncommand that part, the characters are shown correctly. Have I to convert the CharBuffer to UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileReader always uses the platform default encoding. Use

```
InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("index.html"), "UTF-8")
```